# Scala Passing Sequence of Functions as Argument Type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pipeline

In order to pipeline a variety of data transformation functions I want to iterate through a sequence of functions and apply each to the initial input. For a single input it would be something like this:

```
def transformPipeline(f: MyType => MyType)(val: MyType): MyType = {...}
```

How can I define this function such that instead of accepting a single `f: MyType => MyType` it would accept something like `Seq(f: MyType => MyType)`

e.g.

```
def transformPipeline(f: Seq[MyType => MyType])(val: MyType): MyType = {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then this might be what you're after.

```
def transformPipeline(fs: Seq[MyType => MyType])(init: MyType): MyType =
  fs.foldLeft(init)((v, f) => f(v))
```

Tested like so:

```
type MyType = Int

transformPipeline(Seq(_+1,_*2,_/3))(17)  //res0: MyType = 12
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks